# Calling REST API from browser

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created REST API based on this tutorial:
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Using+the+REST+API

When I call this service using Curl, output is what I expected.

If I call REST service using browser (Firefox in this case),
"Save as" window is opened with data type "application/soap+xml".

How I can change content type (to application/xml) so I can see result in browser?
I am using WSO2 ESB version 4.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

To test your REST API and specify the headers of your choice and other information, you can use an extension such as [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient) (Firefox) or [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) (Chrome)

Comment: Thank you for this information, but sometimes (or very often) data content of REST message would be nice to view on browser.

Comment: @Jaba, with an extension like Postman you can view the result in the browser, and you can even have it nicely formatted so that it's more readable.